# Spring-Security-Web import errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pom.xml, jakarta-migration

I'm currently tasked with upgrading our codebase to Java 11 (Still out of date, I know, but that's the requirement)

I changed out all of the old javax packages for Jakarta, and updated all of the Spring and Spring-Security packages, but I'm still running into an error

One of the classes is extending `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, but that package in particular is still looking for `javax.servlet.Filter` and causing the compilation to fail and an error of `The hierarchy of the type <class name> is inconsistent`

I have spring-security-web at version 5.8.6, so I'm not sure why it's still trying to look for javax when the rest of the Spring and Spring-Security packages seem to be using Jakarta without issue

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question to hopefully save someone else a headache in the future

The source of this error was due to a misunderstanding of Spring Framework

Version 5.3.29 that I was using does not implement Jakarta, and is still using the old JavaX packages

The first version of Spring Framework that uses Jakarta is 6.0, which is not compatible prior to JDK 17, causing any interactions between the updated Tomcat 10 and Spring Framework 5 to break

Therefore the functionality I was trying to implement here was impossible